# Decreasing scroll wheel volume control step size

Tags: 16.10, volume-control

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 with default Unity. The volume control in the title bar allows changing volume with the scroll wheel when hovering over the icon. But the step is a bit too big, I'd like the volume to change a bit less with one scroll wheel click.

Comment: Even with function keys the steps are big. I like that mind you unlike the TV remote which has 100 steps and takes too long to turn down.